# Selenium Jar File 2.44.0

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to know whether Selenium jar 2.44.0 (new one) supports Firefox 35.0.1 or not. Please suggest.

Getting error :

org.openqa.selenium.firefox.NotConnectedException: Unable to connect to host

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know , Selenium latest version supports till firefox 33.0.

Still I think you should check browser compatibility with selenium versions before start work so please check at below :

[Selenium with browser compatibility](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/java/CHANGELOG)